# PhpStorm compress code into one big mess

Tags: phpstorm, obfuscation

Does PhpStorm has a functionality to make code hard to read by making it one big mess?

I have HTML & JavaScript project which has lot's of code ready to be put in production use. I want to make it harder to read if someone is searching source code. I know there is pretty print features in browser to overcome this but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPStorm doesn't have any built-in functions for this. You might want to checkout [phpprotector](http://www.phpprotect.info/) or [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)

Comment: YUI Compressor looks exactly what I'm looking for! I post my results here later.

Comment: @Terhoraj if it helped you may be u should consider making this answer the accepted one / upvote

Comment: Yep, YUI did the job! if someone else is reading this, here's how to run that jar file under windows:

java -jar C:\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar somefile.js -o somefile-min.js